# AngularJS: Setting up default input values when the page is initially loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an web app with AngularJS & Bootstrap. In my application there is a bootstrap modal on  main dashboard. This modal is showing up on a toggle button. In the main dashboard there are some charts & grids. The input fields for drawing these charts and grids are  coming from that modal.

This is the main dashboard html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title></title>

<!-- angularJS scripts -->
<script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>


<script src="../mvc/constants/constants.js"></script>
<script src="../mvc/service/Service.js"></script>
<script src="../mvc/controller/DashboardController.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- KENDO scripts for creating charts -->

<script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="DashboardController" ng-init="initModal()">

<div id="mainContainer">
<div class="demo-section k-content wide">

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h1 style="padding-left: 15px">
            HotelName<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"
                        style="color: #6789DA; cursor: pointer; position: relative; top: -10px; font-size: 27px;"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hotelDetailModal"></i>
        </h1>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 15px">{{packageString}}</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 15px">{{requestRoomTypeName}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">


        <!-- ng-click="initialMethod()" -->
        <h4 style="text-align: right; margin-top: 14px; margin-right: 20px;">{{algoName}}
        </h4>
        <h6 style="padding-right: 20px; float: right">{{startDateString}}
            {{endDateString}}</h6>

        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 2px; float: right;"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changeSearch"
                ng-click="initialMethod()">Edit criteria</button> -->
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="grid" class="demo-section k-content wide"></div>
</div>

<div id="example" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="chartContainer" class="col-md-7">
    <div id="competitorPriceChart"></div>

</div>

</div>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="hotelDetailModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h1>Hotel Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label>Schema Type</label> <select
                        class="form-control" required="required"
                        ng-model="schemaType"
                        ng-change="changeSchemaType()">
                    <option value="0">Hotel</option>
                    <option value="1">Destination</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class=col-xs-6>
                    <label>Sub Type</label> <select
                        class="form-control" id="subType"
                        ng-options="sub_type.cityCode for sub_type in subTypeList"
                        ng-model="subType" required="required"
                        ng-change="getHotelDataByDestination()"

                        value="{{sub_type.cityName}}">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden=true>Select
                        Option
                    </option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <label>Hotel</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <select class="form-control"
                            ng-options="hotel.hotelName for hotel in hotelList"
                            ng-model="hotel" required="required"
                            value="{{hotel}}"
                            ng-change="getRoomTypeByHotelName();getMealPlanByHotelName();">
                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden=true>Select
                            Option
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label>Room Type</label> <select
                        class="form-control"
                        ng-options="roomType.roomTypeName for roomType in roomTypeList"
                        ng-model="roomType" required="required"
                        value="{{roomType}}">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden=true>Select
                        Option
                    </option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label>Meal Plan</label> <select
                        class="form-control"
                        ng-options="mealPlan.description for mealPlan in mealPlanList"
                        ng-model="mealPlan" required="required"
                        value="{{mealPlan}}">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden=true>Select
                        Option
                    </option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label>Rooms</label>
                    <input id="rooms"
                           class="form-control" required="required"
                           ng-model="rooms"
                           type="number"/>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label>Adults</label>
                    <input id="adults"
                           class="form-control" required="required"
                           ng-model="adults"
                           type="number"/>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label>Children</label>
                    <input id="kids"
                           class="form-control" required="required"
                           ng-model="kids"
                           type="number"/>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Nights</label>
                    <input id="nights"
                           class="form-control" required="required"
                           ng-model="nights"
                           type="number"/>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label style="margin: 15px 0">Departure Date</label> <input
                        type="date" class="form-control"

                        ng-model="departureDate">
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button ng-click="detailCtrlViewModel.submit()"
                        class="btn btn-default" style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button ng-click="submit()"
                    class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;"
                    data-dismiss="modal">SUBMIT
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When the app is running it should show the main page with all the charts & grids. i.e. there should be default values for inputs when the page is loading.

The modal-body field(drop down menus) are populating from the database.

My **DashboardController** is as follows.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['DataService']);
myApp.controller('DashboardController', function ($scope, DataService) {

$scope.rooms = 1;
$scope.adults = 1;
$scope.kids = 0;
$scope.nights = 7;
$scope.departureDate = new Date();
$scope.schemaType = 1;
$scope.caclulateOn = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);


$scope.initModal = function () {
    console.log('initModal');
    $scope.changeSchemaType();

    $scope.getHotelDataByDestination();
};

$scope.changeSchemaType = function () {
    $scope.subTypeList = [];
    if ($scope.schemaType == "0") {
        $scope.subTypeList.push({
            cityName : "5 star",
            cityCode : "city1",
        }, {
            cityName : "4 star or above",
            cityCode : "city2",
        });
        $scope.subType = $scope.subTypeList[0];
    } else {
        $scope.subTypeList.push({cityCode:"CITY1",cityName:"CITY1"},{cityCode:"city2",cityName:"city2"});
        $scope.subType = $scope.subTypeList[0];
        console.log($scope.subType);

    }

}

$scope.getHotelDataByDestination = function () {
    console.log($scope.subType);
    console.log($scope.subType.cityCode);
    var destinationCode = $scope.subType.cityCode;

    DataService.getHotelByDestinationService(destinationCode).success(
            function(data) {

                $scope.hotelList = [];
                for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {                     
                    $scope.hotelList.push({hotelId: data[k].hotelId, hotelName:data[k].hotelName });            
                }
                if(destinationCode == "CITY1"){
                    $scope.hotel = $scope.hotelList[17];
                    console.log($scope.hotel);

                }else if(destinationCode == "CITY2"){
                    $scope.hotel = $scope.hotelList[2];
                    console.log($scope.hotel);
                }else {
                    $scope.hotel = $scope.hotelList[0];
                }
                $scope.getRoomTypeByHotelName();
                $scope.getMealPlanByHotelName();

            }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

$scope.getRoomTypeByHotelName = function () {
    console.log($scope.hotel);
    var hotelName = $scope.hotel.hotelName;
    DataService.getRoomTypeByHotelNameService(hotelName).success(
            function(data) {
                $scope.roomTypeList = [];
                for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {                     
                    $scope.roomTypeList.push({roomTypeName: data[k].roomTypeName });            
                }

                $scope.roomType = $scope.roomTypeList[0];
            }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });

}

$scope.getMealPlanByHotelName = function () {
    var hotelName = $scope.hotel.hotelName;
    DataService.getMealPlanByHotelNameService(hotelName).success(
            function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                $scope.mealPlanList= [];
                for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {                     
                    $scope.mealPlanList.push({code: data[k].code, description: data[k].description });          
                }
                $scope.mealPlan = $scope.mealPlanList[0];
            }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log('submit');
    console.log($scope.rooms);
    console.log($scope.adults);
    console.log($scope.kids);
    console.log($scope.nights);
    console.log($scope.departureDate);
    console.log($scope.hotel);
    console.log($scope.roomType);
    console.log($scope.mealPlan);

    // call function to draw charts and grid
    $scope.displayTableView($scope.hotel.hotelId, $scope.roomType.roomTypeName, $scope.departureDate, $scope.nights,
            $scope.mealPlan.code);
    $scope.initCompetitorPriceChart($scope.hotel.hotelId, $scope.departureDate, $scope.nights, $scope.mealPlan.code);

}



});
```

When the page is loading it calls **initModal** function & populate all the drop down field in the modal. But actually I am getting an empty page, them I toggle the modal I can select fields an clicks the submit button, then it draws charts. Initially it doesn't draw any graph or grid. The thing I really want is show main page with charts, those charts should be drawn for default input fields(when the modal is loading default values are the first element in the drop down). Again, once I select new values from the modal & submit it should reload the main page with new charts based on newly selected values.

Hope you clear what I am mentioning. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATED**

This is the response right after

```
DataService.getHotelByDestinationService(destinationCode).success(
            function(data) {}

[{"hotelId":26047,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Anahita Residence and Villas","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27751},{"hotelId":26341,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Belle Mare Plage (Hotel CONSTANCE)","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27911},{"hotelId":26364,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Blumarine Attitude Hotel","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27874},{"hotelId":26362,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Friday Attitude Hotel","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27873},{"hotelId":26965,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Heritage Awali","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27934},{"hotelId":26963,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Heritage le Telfair","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27931},{"hotelId":26306,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Hotel Angsana Balaclava Mauritius","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27971},{"hotelId":26046,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Hotel Sofitel So Mauritius","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27752},{"hotelId":26301,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Long Beach Resort","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27753},{"hotelId":26763,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"LUX* Belle Mare","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27914},{"hotelId":26762,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"LUX* Grand Gaube","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27913},{"hotelId":26761,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"LUX* Le Morne","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27892},{"hotelId":26721,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Maradiva Villas Resort & Spa","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27891},{"hotelId":26330,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Mont Choisy Beach Villas","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27932},{"hotelId":26331,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Mystik Apart Hotel","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27933},{"hotelId":26048,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"One and Only Le Saint Geran","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27791},{"hotelId":26328,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Preskil Beach Resort","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27771},{"hotelId":26361,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Recif Attitude Hotel","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27872},{"hotelId":26329,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Solana Beach Resort","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27792},{"hotelId":26743,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Tamassa All-Inclusive Resort","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27893},{"hotelId":26541,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"The Ravenala Attitude Hotel","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27871},{"hotelId":26821,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"The Saint Regis Mauritius Resort","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27936},{"hotelId":26053,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"The Sands Suites Resort and Spa","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27772},{"hotelId":26822,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"The Westin Turtle Bay Resort & Spa","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27935},{"hotelId":26764,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Villas de LUX* Belle Mare","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27912},{"hotelId":26363,"hotelCode":null,"hotelName":"Zilwa Attitude Hotel","rating":null,"cityCode":null,"holidayId":27875}]
```

Thank You

Comment: why don't you call submit() on initModal ?

Comment: This does not seem like the minimal code to repro the issue.

Comment: @madalinivascu, I tried so, then it gives **Cannot read property 'hotelId' of undefined**.console.log($scope.hotel);
        console.log($scope.roomType);
        console.log($scope.mealPlan); These lines print undefined

Comment: @Arg0n, this is what I amt trying

Comment: could you add console.log(data) right after success response of DataService.getHotelByDestinationService(destinationCode)

Comment: @mtamma: I have posted

Comment: if you add submit() on initModal it will return undefine hotelId because '$scope.hotel' define on asynchronus call in 'DataService.getHotelByDestinationService...' on $scope.getHotelDataByDestination.

Comment: @mtamma, thanks for your comment, Then how can I fixed that issue ?

Comment: try to define these scope variable right after you define $scope.calculateOn. --> $scope.hotel = {};
$scope.roomType = {};
$scope.mealPlan = {};

Comment: @mtamma, I tried. Then it calls chart creating functions. But console.log($scope.hotel);
        console.log($scope.roomType);
        console.log($scope.mealPlan); statement in initModal function prints empty objects -> Object {}

Comment: where do you put the execusion of submit function?

Comment: move the submit() function to the line right after $scope.roomType = $scope.roomTypeList[0];  on DataService.getRoomTypeByHotelNameService

Comment: Then it doesn't get $scope.mealPlan. It's am empty object

Comment: I think it;s becz $scope.mealPlan is define  on asynchronus call in DataService.getMealPlanByHotelNameService(hotelName).success(

Comment: yup you are right :) so then call all the async function and add the submit right on the success scope.

Comment: If I call submit() right after DataService.getMealPlanByHotelNameService(hotelName), then it doesn't get $scope.roomType

Comment: In my case it calls two service $scope.getRoomTypeByHotelName() &       $scope.getMealPlanByHotelName(); paralally. Any idea to manage this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116058/discussion-between-rose18-and-mtamma).

Answer (score 2):

to display the charts during pageload, you should prepopulate the values required for the charts.
After that, run the functions for rendering the charts.

Regards,
Malikai

Code:

```
$scope.initModal = function () {
    console.log('initModal');
    $scope.changeSchemaType();

    $scope.getHotelDataByDestination();
    preselectChartValues();
    updateCharts();
};

function preselectChartValues() {
    $scope.hotel = {}; // some hotel
    $scope.roomType = {} // some room type
    // ...
}

function updateCharts() {
    $scope.displayTableView(
        $scope.hotel.hotelId,
        $scope.roomType.roomTypeName,
        $scope.departureDate, 
        $scope.nights,
        $scope.mealPlan.code);
    $scope.initCompetitorPriceChart(
        $scope.hotel.hotelId, 
        $scope.departureDate, 
        $scope.nights, 
        $scope.mealPlan.code);
}
```